# Handle dropdown menu value

Tags: flutter, dart

Good time
I have two dropdowns on one page
The first is a list of cars and the second is the model of the cars.
Now, when I select Mercedes in the first drop-down menu, for example, I want the exact model name of the car brand to appear in the second drop-down menu.
For example, I choose Mercedes and in the next drop down, the list of Mercedes cars will be shown to me.
How can I handle it?

I am a newbie. And maybe it is better to give a more comprehensive explanation

Comment: can you include your current snippet, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73446365/10157127) may answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle this.
You can track the selected field, by adding it as a variable on your application, and everytime you select a new value, that variable is changed  ex:

```
manufacturer = "Mercedes"
```

You can either have a variable (flag) in the builder that changes what is presented depending on its value,
Ex: when a new value is selected on the first dropdown, you change the value of a variable, and the second dropdown loads a list based on that value.
Ex:

```
if (manufacturer == "Mercedes") { // load mercedes list on 2nd dropdown }
```

or

Create a state change where you load different values to the list depending on the selected value, with a stateChange of a StatefulWidget.

Comment: I don't think first approach is good

Answer (score 0):

Use Map to store the Manufacturer. For e.g. :

```
Map<String,String> manufacturer = {'1':'BMW','2':'Toyota'};
```

And also store list of cars using a map like this:

```
Map<String,List<String>> cars = {
    '1':{'BMW car1','BMW car2'},
    '2':{'Toyota car1','Toyota car2'},
};
```

Then create a key variable which will stored key of selected brand.

```
String key ='1';
```

Then U can now choose the cars u desire using the key u chose for brand in dropdown.